# How do i compare every PC name from a multiobject array to a single object array

Tags: arrays, powershell

Hi Powershell newbie alert,

I am trying to compare the computer name of my $getADComp function (CN) with the output of $WSUSArr.

I want to know which PC's are in the WSUS but not and the AD and vice versa. I want the PC names to go in 2 diffrent result arrays so i can use these again later

Eventually i want something like this

```
$separator = "."

$GetWSUSComp = Get-wsuscomputer -UpdateServer $wsus
$GetADComp   = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property CN, CanonicalName, Description | Select-Object CN, CanonicalName, Description

$WSUSArr       = @()


for ($i = 0; $i -lt $GetWSUSComp.Count; $i++){

    $WSUSArr += $GetWSUSComp[$i].FullDomainName.split($separator)[0].ToUpper()

}


Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $WSUSArr -DifferenceObject $GetADComp
```

If there is a more efficient way to do this feel free to make use of another method (hash table, etc.)

I have another array which is called $WSUSArr which contains the names of all the computer that are connected to the WSUS server i will have to compare those two lists with eachother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not go for an array of **objects** ?

```
$GetADComp = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property CN, DistinguishedName, Description |
             Select-Object CN, DistinguishedName, Description
```

This way you avoid gathering all properties with `-Property *` where you only want three.

Every property of items in the array can be accessed by using

```
$GetADComp[$index].CN
$GetADComp[$index].DistinguishedName
$GetADComp[$index].Description
```

and compared with an array of CN's like

```
$GetADComp | Where-Object { $_.CN -eq $WSUSArr[$index] }
```

---

In order to compare the computer CN's with the objects returned from the `Get-ADComputer` cmdlet:

**1.**
Get the computers that are both in AD and in the WSUS array.
If you want this to be a simple string array of just the CN's, do this:

```
$ADcomputersInWsus = $GetADComp | Where-Object { $WSUSArr -contains $_.CN } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CN
```

Without the `Select-Object`, this will get you an array of objects with three 
properties: CN, DistinguishedName, Description.

```
$ADcomputersInWsus = $GetADComp | Where-Object { $WSUSArr -contains $_.CN }
# An object array like this is perfect for saving as CSV:
# $ADcomputersInWsus | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\ADcomputersInWsus.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

**2.**
Get a list of computers that are in WSUS, but **not** in AD:

```
# ($GetADComp).CN returns an string array with just the CN's, just like the $WSUSArr
$WsusComputersNotInAD = $WSUSArr | Where-Object { ($GetADComp).CN -notcontains $_ }
```

**3.**
Get a list of AD computers that are not in WSUS:

```
$ADcomputersNotInWsus = $GetADComp | Where-Object { $WSUSArr -notcontains $_.CN } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CN
```

---

Note, the `$WsusComputersNotInAD` is derived from the `$WSUSArr` string array and is therefore also an array of **strings**, not objects.
To save that to file, either use:

```
$WsusComputersNotInAD | Out-File -FilePath "C:\XXX\XXX\WSUSCompNotInAD.txt" -Force
```

Or convert to an object array and use `Export-Csv` like the other results:

```
$WsusComputersNotInAD | ForEach-Object { [PsCustomObject]@{'ComputerName' = $_}} | 
    Export-Csv -Path "C:\XXX\XXX\WSUSCompNotInAD.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This will work but how do i run this every single PC from the AD array against the whole list of WSUS PC's

Comment: @claeys Sorry for the late reply. I have edited my answer and added code for comparing the arrays

Comment: One comment why do i get length values in the exported CSV files.
#$WsusComputersNotInAD | export-csv -Path "C:\XXX\XXX\WSUSCompNotInAD.csv" -NoTypeInformation

Comment: @claeys That is because `$WsusComputersNotInAD` is not an array of objects but a string array, derived from the `$WSUSArr` string array. I have edited my answer to show how to save that to file too.